# pytest-django could not find a Django project

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

Trying to configure pytest with django, the project already has a lot of test not written with pytest (written with unittest) but I am trying to get them run with pytest so I can write pytest tests and get it work with old tests.

I know pytest-django checks for the manage.py file in the root dir of a django project but this project the manage.py file is not in the root dir so I guess that's why the error below is thrown when I run `pytest` however running pytest and supplying a particular file works. How do I specify where manage.py is? As I can't find this in the [documentation](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html)

```
pytest-django could not find a Django project (no manage.py file could be found). 
You must explicitly add your Django project to the Python path to have it picked up.
```

Comment: I don't know exactly how to solve your problem but i think that documentation would help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/

Comment: Unless you have some project-specific code in your `manage.py`, it is enough to specify the correct django settings module (either via `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env var, or via `--ds` arg, or in `pytest.ini`). Also, you have to make sure that all project sources are found in `sys.path`, but that's all.

Comment: If you do have some test-specific code in your `manage.py` (it's not just a shim with adjusting the settings) and you run your tests via `python manage.py test`, then [read this](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-use-manage-py-test-with-pytest-django).

Comment: You can explicitly show your paths to pytest:
https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managing_python_path.html#managing-the-python-path-explicitly
Probably you could also think about this: https://pypi.org/project/pytest-pythonpath/

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I created a configure file named `pytest.ini` in the `tests` folder with the following content:

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = ../bitpin
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = bitpin.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

Repository tree:

```
bitpin-repo
├── bitpin
│   ├── bitpin
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── manage.py
├── tests
│   ├── test_models.py
│   ├── pytest.ini
│   └── conftest.py
└── setup.py
```

---

[**NOTE**]

- If the `tests/` is next to the project, replace `bitpin` with `.`:

```
[pytest]
pythonpath = .
```

Answer (score 3):

you can define a python path to python commands that you want to run:

```
PYTHONPATH=/your/path/to/your/django/project/ pytest
```

or export your pythonpath before you run the pytest command:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/your/path/to/your/django/project/

pytest
```

Comment: Yeah this would work if we want to run from any directory... But then I figured out that I have to cd into the directory containing manage.py and run the command it works equally

Answer (score 1):

As a standard practice, you should add a `setup.cfg` file to your root, with the following block -

```
[tool:pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<package_name>.settings.py
```

You can later use the same file for linters by adding specific blocks for them.